# Overriding Auto Generated EntityValidationErrors MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

I have an elaborate business listing form that I want people to fill out but it's to much to do in one go so I've broken it down into a four stages. The first stage creates the business and works fine but the second, third and fourth are then variations of the scaffolded "Edit" form with parts missing.

My problem is then I can't get past the EntityValidationErrors and get the following error:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Which I understand but don't know how to fix?

THis is in MVC5 and .NET4.5 and a few things have changed that I need to work out!

I also have this all running on `http://localhost//` so any errors I get only come to me via the browser, not VS.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a bunch of hiddedFor()'s on the pages for now!

I will have to go back and create view models for the different views but this works for now, time is money!